# ETL from mongo to bigquery

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery, etl, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm looking to build an ETL flow from mongoDB to google BigQuery. I was thinking below ETL flow
MongoDB ->Google Data Fusion-> Google BigQuery

It looks like google data fusion doesn't have connector to MongoDb.

Is there any other approach to build this ETL flow?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a JDBC driver for MongoDB to Data Fusion following these steps:

1. Open your Data Fusion instance.
2. Click + to add an entity and upload a driver.

[image]

3. On the “Upload  Driver” tag, drag or browse the renamed JAR file.
4. On the “Driver Configuration” tab:

- Name: Create a name for the driver (cdata.jdbc.mongodb) and make note
  of the name.
- Class Name: Set the JDBC class name:
  (cdata.jdbc.mongodb.MongoDBDriver).

[image]

5. Click "Finish"

Now that you have created your JDBC driver, you are ready to work with MongoDB into Data Fusion pipelines. To do so, be sure to follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the pipeline studio to create a new pipeline.
2. From the “Source” options, click on “Database” to add a source for the JDBC driver.

[image]

3. Click on "Properties" on the Database source to edit the properties (NOTE: To use the JDBC Driver in Google Data Fusion, you will need a license (full or trial) and a Runtime Key (RTK)).

- Set the Label
- Set Reference Name to a value for any future references (i.e.:
  cdata-mongodb)
- Set Plugin Type to "jdbc"
- Set Connection String to the JDBC URL for MongoDB. For example:

`jdbc:mongodb:RTK=5246...;Server=MyServer;Port=27017;Database=test;User=test;Password=Password;`

- Set the Server, Database, User, and Password connection properties to
  connect to MongoDB.

4. From the "Sink"tab, click to add a destination sink.
5. Click on "Properties" on the BigQuery sink to edit the properties.

- Set the Label
- Set Reference Name to a value like mongodb-bigquery
- Set Project ID to a specific Google BigQuery Project ID (or leave as the default, "auto-detect")
- Set Dataset to a specific Google BigQuery dataset
- Set Table to the name of the table you wish to insert MongoDB data into

[image]

I followed the tutorial on [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mongodb-jdbc-google-data-fusion.rst) page and it helped me; I hope it helps you.